# Bevel an inset face with resulting clean edges

Tags: modeling, bevel

When I bevel this Edge (which is parallel to X-Axis)
[image: picture 2]

I always end up like this:
[image: picture 3]

But actually I want this (without the faces that I colored blue)
[image: picture 1]

I extruded the inset face without further scaling and moved it inwards the x-axis After extruding it a second time.

How can I achieve the beveling results in proper edges/faces?

Link to my .blend-file:
https://www.file-upload.net/download-14584958/bevel_problem.blend.html

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: I added a link in the question.

Comment: question: how did you get the edges smooth? did you apply a modifier?

Comment: I selected some (not all) faces and Set Face>Shade Smooth. I then added Loop-Cuts where needed to get a prettier result. (No modifier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a somewhat shorter solution, but it still requires a bunch of work.

Create the bevel:

[image: beveled area]

Use the knife tool to replace the missing edges:

[image: add the missing edges]

Select and delete the edges you don't want, using *dissolve edges*:

[image: select dissolve edges]

and there you go:

[image: the desired topology]

This leaves you with all quads in the replaced area, but a concave quad can be just as bad as an n-gon.

Comment: Nice! Always forget about the knive. And finally adding an edge to Split the Face into 2 triangles should then bring up a perfect result regarding rendering etc, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if two tris or 1 concave quad would be worse.  Either way don't forget to set auto smooth in the object's properties.

Answer (score 7):

I think my workflow is similar to @Chris's, but because I'm working to a Subdivision Surface, there's less topology. I did this on your model, but have reproduced the moves on a smaller one to illustrate more easily.

[image]

All with Snap set to 'To: Vertex' and 'With: Active'...

I deleted your existing extrusion, filled the hole, duplicated it out along its normal axis. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, bevelled it in place, away from the rest of the model.

Because Subdiv. is coming, 2 segments will do, in the bevel. Now to prepare a hole for it...

[image]

(Left) A couple of horizontal loops were needed to create edges for a hole with a nice even margin all the way round the bevelled face. Then, (Middle,) loops were cut and snapped into place along X and Y axes to match the bevel vertices. (Right) The hole was deleted, and the bevelled face snapped flush again.

The original loops from the rectangular face were dissolved away, leaving matching vertices in the hole and the new face.

[image]

Now, since I have the shipped add-on 'F2' activated, I can fill one face in the gap, and, having selected the leading edge, hold down <kbd>F</kbd>, to fill the rest. You can cut a loop through the new faces, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> .. <kbd>E</kbd>venly slide it (with <kbd>F</kbd> to flip if necessary) to make a neat isolating rim around the new face.

The rest is extrusions and insets, or bevels, whichever you prefer. I cut extra loops near the corners to hold the edges straight.   After Subdiv:

[image]

Maybe this way is just my habit, rather than 'the best'.. but I personally find it easier to work to a hole in situations like this, where you need a partial bevel. You don't want the consequences of the bevel propagating over your nice clean mesh.

Comment: P.S. If you _did_ want to work to subdiv, you would need to reduce the number of segments in the moulding around the rims of your case. 1/3 of that would do.

Answer (score 4):

ok, i don't know a better solution, but it works ;)

I am sure, moonboots will provide a two click solution ... ;)

1. select these 2 edges

[image]

2. <kbd>x</kbd> -> delete edges

[image]

3. select this edge and bevel your edge as you want

[image]

[image]

4. reconstruct your old mesh by selecting these two guys -> <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

5. select these guys -> <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

[image]

6. select that guy -> copy y coord

[image]

7. select that guy -> <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> -> <kbd>escape</kbd> -> paste y coord from 7)

[image]
[image]

8. ...and so on until your mesh is closed again

[image]

Comment: Thank you, pretty hacky but seem to work. Thinking further about the Problem which, on first look, seemsled actually simple, I thought the desired solution may end up in some dort of Triangel-faces. Like a Quartier of a cylinders Triangel-fan at the beveled Front Face.

Comment: i am pretty sure the pros are coming up with better solutions...just wait ;)